# Android XML Drawable: Rounded Rectangle With Inner Edge Gradient

Tags: android, xml, gradient, drawable, layer-list

I'm currently drawing a simple rounded rectangle using an XML drawable (black BG for contrast):

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

[image: Rectangle]

What I would like to achieve is adding an inside outline/glow that is a gradient so that it looks like this:

[image: Rectangle with gradiant]

I know it will most likely involve several XML gradient elements in a layer list, but where I get stuck creating this is figuring out how to:

- Have the gradient follow the curves in the corners since they are rounded (always face towards the center of the rectangle, or as close as possible)
- Avoid the effect having double intensity in the corners like it is in the example. This will happen if 4 gradients are simply overlapped or a radial gradient stretched to a ellipse is used. The density of the outer color needs to be consistent all the way around the rectangle, or as close as possible

It is highly preferable if feasible that the implementation is modifiable so that:

- I can control how far into the rectangle the gradient reaches
- I can control how quickly the gradient fades at any given distance (control its density/intensity)
- I can remove any side from the gradient so that I can have only 1 or 2 edges and their corners glow if needed

This is a perfect example of what I need except that it is obviously much simpler to do with a circle and a radial gradient. I need this consistent pattern but with the rounded rectangle:

[image: Circle Example]

Comment: it would be better to create 9-patch png image

Comment: @karan could you add an example?

Comment: @obliviocth, did you find a solution? I'm at the same point..

Comment: @Tobi Sadly no I did not. I haven't worked on this project for some time and do mean to come up with a better solution, but at the time I just resorted to using a medium res PNG, figuring I'd make it a 9 patch later.